# Bayes' theorem in 1-d EM algorithm

Tags: bayesian, latent-variable, expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I'm watching a video on the EM algorithm,

[image]

When we use Bayes' Theorem to calculate $b_i$, how do I find $P(b)$ and $P(a)$ initially? It says we can estimate the priors $P(b)$ and $P(a)$ but that's once we have at least one value $b_i$. Should I simply let $P(b)$ and $P(a)$ be 1 to begin with?

Also, why does it say we *could* estimate the priors? Don't we have to in order to calculate $b_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty, and the potential danger, of the EM algorithm is that no matter where you start, you will always (for most problems) converge to a local mode.  It's always a good idea when running such a mode finding algorithm to initialize it with various starting values to make sure that you found the global mode, as opposed to a local mode.

For $p(a)= \tau$ and $p(b)= 1-\tau$, you have to start with starting values for $\tau$ just like the other parameters.  The parameter $\tau$ will be updated during each M-step of the EM algorithm and will not be fixed from the start as one would normally think of a prior.  See the gaussian mixture example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm).

Comment: Could I simply use $P(b) = (b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_n)/n$ and $P(a) = 1 - P(b)$ and update it every iteration? If so, what should I initialize the values to at the very beginning? It appears the other parameters can be picked pretty much at random, is that the case here?

Comment: You could start there, assuming you had starting guesses for $b_1$, $b_2$, ..., $b_n$.  Where you start determines where you finish, so if you have a good starting value, you could make it to the global mode.  In general, it can be difficult to select a starting value that will get you to the global mode as opposed to a local mode, which is why it would be better to run an EM algorithm from each of several different starting values.

Comment: But see there's the whole chicken and egg thing where I can't estimate my $b_i$'s without having my $P(b)$ and $P(a)$ and I'm not sure how to go about making good starting guesses. Perhaps I could assume the priors to be equal for the first few $b_i$ calculations? I will make sure to try several starting values for the parameters of the gaussians

Comment: Indeed, there's not really a great solution to how to initialize the parameters or the latent variables, the $b_i$'s.  This is precisely why you should run it from various starting points.  You should experiment with different starting values for $P(b)$ as well!

Comment: How will I know when I've actually found the global mode?

Comment: Good question.  There is no way to prove you have found the global mode unless you apply some other method.  But if you start your algorithm from enough different starting points, it would be reasonable to conclude that whichever mode corresponds to the largest observed data likelihood would be the global mode.  The observed data likelihood in this case corresponds to the mixture of two normals with parameters and weights equal to the mixture proportions estimated by EM.